# Force Close when Adding ToolBar to Java Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am adding a Toolbar to my App that has about 3 Activities.

I added a Toolbar to the first 2 Activities but when I tried to add Toolbar to the third one, the activity crashed.

When I open my app and go to the third Activity (I named it "profile") my app crashes.

```
package com.mrad4tech.app.m4taudiomanager;

import android.app.ActionBar; 
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton; 
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Button modeBtn;
    private Button increaseBtn;
    private Button decreaseBtn;
    private RadioButton normal;
    private RadioButton silent;
    private RadioGroup ringGroup;
    private TextView status;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;
    private ActionBar supportActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);



        normal = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioNormal);
        silent = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSilent);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        ringGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioRinger);

        modeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mode);
        modeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int selectedId = ringGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find which radioButton is checked by id
                if (selectedId == silent.getId()) {
                    silentEnable(v);
                } else if (selectedId == normal.getId()) {
                    normalEnable(v);
                } else {
                    vibrateEnable(v);
                }
            }
        });

        increaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increase);
        increaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // increase the volume and show the ui
                myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "increase volume",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        decreaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrease);
        decreaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // decrease the volume and show the ui
                myAudioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "decrease volume",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // get the instance of AudioManager class
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    }


    public void vibrateEnable(View view) {
        // set the ring mode to vibrate
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        status.setText("Current Status: Vibrate Mode");
    }

    public void normalEnable(View view) {
        // set the ring mode to loud
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        status.setText("Current Status: Ring Mode");
    }

    public void silentEnable(View view) {
        // set the ring mode to silent
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        status.setText("Current Status: Silent Mode");
    }


}
```

Comment: when adding this                                                                                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Where are you initializing Toolbar ? and post your activity_profile layout.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the crash

Comment: activity_profile.xml   http://mrad4apk.blogspot.com/2015/05/activityprofilexml.html

Comment: i think the problem is in the class,i think there is a missing Method

Comment: @Knossos  her eis the logcat http://mrad4apk.blogspot.com/2015/05/logcat-1.html

Comment: @YuvaRaj <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#283593">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: @Mrad4Tech Check my answer i've posted below. What's your app bar layout file name?

Comment: Thanks Guys @YuvaRaj solved this for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comment you said,

> I get the error when adding this toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

You're getting the error because you are trying to access the ID which doesn't exists. Look here you 've mentioned id as `app_bar_profile`

```
    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar_profile"
     layout="@layout/app_bar_profile"></include>
```

& in code you're  trying like

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar); <- app_bar id doesn't exists
```

So, change the id as `app_bar_profile`

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_profile);
```

Also, i'm not sure whether you 've set a correct layout for toolbar in xml layout. You need to post your app bar layout so that we can examine whether you're doing any mistake like the above.

Comment: am using the same app_bar with another activity and it is working

Comment: You can use same app_bar, but look at the id you've defined for app bar in XML and Java code. What is your app bar layout file name?

Comment: If you are using the same app bar, are you defining the layout `app_bar_profile` in other activities?

Comment: Theeee Bestttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt Thanksss

Comment: the problem was that the id in the <include> is different than that in toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_profile);

Comment: marked as the answer ,i wish i can vote up for you , but i dont have enough reputations

Comment: @Mrad4Tech Yes, that's what i've said & no issues :)